# Order a Dictionary of Lists of objects based on multiple conditions on underlying objects' properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary of lists of (1 or 2) objects; something like this:

```
var groupedFoos = Dictionary<string, List<Foo>>();
```

where the Dictionary key is an ID that's the common ID of the objects in the List. The object looks like this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public enum Priority {get; set;} // High=0 or Low=1
    public int Score {get; set;}
}
```

A `List<Object>` can have only High Priority, only Low or both. The final order needs to have the same layout, but with order, so as `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IOrderedEnumerable<Foo>>>` where the order is:

1. Highest Score of High Priority
2. High + Low before Only High
3. Highest Score of Low Priority

This is a working solution, but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way:

```
// order each list so that High Priority comes before Low
var orderedFoos = groupedFoos
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Value
        .OrderBy(foo => foo.Priority));

return orderedFoos
    .OrderByDescending(group => group.Value.Count(foo => foo.Priority == High)) // the ones with High Priority first
    .ThenByDescending(group => group.Value.First().Score) // Highest Priority first
    .ThenByDescending(group => group.Value.Count)); // the ones that have both first
```

Comment: Remove the `.ToList() `

Comment: You say "The final order" - the final order of what? A `Dictionary<,>` has no order. Your `orderedFoos` seems to have nothing to do with your problem description???

Comment: Right, the returned object will not be modified further, but I understand that in order to safely retain the order I have to keep it as `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<Foo>>>`